# page_number is always 1 in paginate_queryset in PageNumberPagination

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

My view is as follows:

```
class ApplicationApplicantsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Applicant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApplicantSerializer

    def list(self, request, application_pk=None):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(application__pk=application_pk)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)


        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Following is the paginate_queryset method

```
 def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    """
    Paginate a queryset if required, either returning a
    page object, or `None` if pagination is not configured for this view.
    """
    self._handle_backwards_compat(view)

    page_size = self.get_page_size(request)
    if not page_size:
        return None

    paginator = DjangoPaginator(queryset, page_size)
    page_number = request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, 1)
    if page_number in self.last_page_strings:
        page_number = paginator.num_pages

    try:
        self.page = paginator.page(page_number)
    except InvalidPage as exc:
        msg = self.invalid_page_message.format(
            page_number=page_number, message=six.text_type(exc)
        )
        raise NotFound(msg)

    if paginator.num_pages > 1 and self.template is not None:
        # The browsable API should display pagination controls.
        self.display_page_controls = True

    self.request = request
    return list(self.page)
```

But on accessing the url with

> http://url?page=2

the page_number variable in paginate_queryset in PageNumberPagination is 1. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I can't see where you use the get parameter in that section of your code, you seem to just set page to what is returned from your method

Comment: I didn't get your comment. I just edited my question. Can you look at it again? @Sayse

Comment: You don't seem to pass in the request to that method so I can't see how its getting it in there, I might be missing something though..

Comment: No worries, you may want to add an answer to your own question explaining the problem. it may help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

set this dynamically :
`page_number = request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, 1)`
instead of setting it to 1